# alignment issue inside div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am facing problem while aligning the element inside div.

I want something like this

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
|<P>   | <input type = text> | imagebutton here |
|here  |  here               |                  |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

But i am getting something like

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
|<P>   |                                        |
|here  |                                        |
|       <input type = text>  |                  |
|        here                |                  |
|                             imagebutton here  |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

So there is some issue that make next element in `div` to be displayed below the current element, i.e if i can align `<input>`  horizontally to the `<p>`, i think that will give the solution.

Below is my attempt:

css part

```
.imagewrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-left: 70%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    height: 35%;
}
.textwrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    height: 35%;
}

.msg_wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:lime;
    margin-left:5%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

html side

```
<div id="searchClass">
<p class="msg_wrapper"><b>Class</b></p>
<input id="txt_class"   style="background-color: Aqua; class = textwrapper >
<input type="image" id="searchclassimg" class="imagewrapper" src="./resource/search-button.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this html :

```
        <div id="searchClass">
          <p class="msg_wrapper"><b>Class</b></p>
          <input style="background-color: Aqua; width:25%; float:left; margin:0 0 0 1%; class = textwrapper" id="txt_class">
          <input type="image" id="searchclassimg" class="imagewrapper" src="./resource/search-button.png">
        </div>
```

OR
CSs code below :

```
<style>    
    .imagewrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin-left: 1%;
        width: 25%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        height: 35%;
    }
    .textwrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: blue;
        margin-left: 30%;
        width: 40%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        height: 35%;
        float: left;
    }
    .msg_wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: lime;
        margin-left: 5%;
        width: 25%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: float kills display, you can remove them they became useless :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey take a took at this example.

[image]

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">        
   #tablecellexamples div { border:1px solid black; width:130px; background-color:#eee }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="tablecellexamples">          
   <div style="display:table-row">   
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus dignissim ipsum a dignissim. Proin mattis orci sit amet quam feugiat lobortis.
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:top">Top aligned</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">Center aligned</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">Bottom aligned</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect (missing a closing quote) corrected in this line:

```
<input id="txt_class" class="textwrapper">
```

you should add the Aqua colour using your css-rules, replacing Blue.

You can make the wrapper div behave as the (containing) row:

```
#searchClass {
    display: table-row;
}
```

You will then want to adjust your margins.

Personally, I would remove all the margin, height, etc., settings and see how it looks firstly, without these.